# Export informatica workflows and mappings in java

Tags: export, mapping, workflow, informatica

I have some mappings and workflows in Power Center Prof. 
Is there any way to export them in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "export them in Java"?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

You can export the mappings with all dependencies as XML file and eventually manipulate it.